# initial state not updating on Dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

**AuthReducer-reducer file**

```
 const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
}
const authReducer = (state = initialState, action: any) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SIGN_IN':
            state = {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
            }
            break;
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
            state = {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: false,
            }
            break;
        default:
            state = {
                isAuthenticated: false,
            }

    }
    return state;
}
export default authReducer;
```

**dispatcher-dispatching action**

```
const authDispatch = useDispatch();
authDispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN'});
```

**Store**

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
user: AuthReducer
```

});
const store = createStore(
rootReducer,
compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

**Result**

```
{isAuthenticated: false}
```

**Result i want**

```
{isAuthenticated: true}
```

> How can I solve this error I am unable to solve this error, please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be.you are returning state incorrectly .

```
switch (action.type) {
        case 'SIGN_IN':
           return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
            }
           
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: false,
            }
           
        default:
           return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: false,
            }

    }
```

Comment: can you post store also .

Comment: can you check are you getting action.type properly.if getting then check  while selecting use selector you need to get state.user.isAuthenticated

Comment: const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: AuthReducer
});
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

Comment: initially get state.user.isAuthenticated  is returning true but after page refresh, it rest to false

Comment: your page shouldnt refresh .if refresh it iwll loose data.thats how redux works .its not local storage so

Comment: how can I preserve my state value?,not change during page refresh. can you please give me some idea?

Comment: single page application no need to refresh unitl you have code splitting. i dont know much deeper into react. but you can avoid using react routing .

Comment: You can store data in local storage and read and set to state  whenever you load page

Answer (score 0):

Reading from your comments I can make that you need to preserve redux data on refresh.
Redux values won't be persisted on refresh it is how redux is,If you intent to preserve values on refresh you need to persist Redux state.

This can be achieved through a npm package "redux-persist".
You can follow this link,documentation is quite descriptive

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

Answer (score 0):

Your `default` case is setting `isAuthenticated: false` - and that `default` case will be hit by every Redux action ever dispatched that is not `"SIGN_IN"` or `"SIGN_OUT"`. So once one other action is dispatched, it returns to `isAuthenticated: false`.

You should have

```
  default:
    return state
```

Also, please note that you are generally writing a very old style of Redux that we do not recommend any more as it requires tons of boilerplate (and this would also not not have happened with modern Redux). You might be following a very outdated tutorial.
For an up-to-date tutorial, please see the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)